# How to change file url in drupal

Tags: drupal-8, filefield

I have a file field. On page it render like

```
<a href="http://somesite/somefolder/9.doc" type="application/msword; length=392192">9.doc</a>
```

I want to make it lock like

```
<a href="http://othersite/otherfolder/9.doc" type="application/msword; length=392192">9.doc</a>
```

**1 :(** I already try to copy core/themes/bartik/templates/classy/field/file-link.html.twig to my theme and rename as FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS to file--link--user-checklist.html.twig but still have core template to render

**2 :(** I try to change url by checklistheme_preprocess_file_link but $variables['link']['#url']->setFileUri($my_url); but have error *this method not exist*

**3 :(** T try to add custom element to checklist_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) but it no show up

I don't know what else I can do

Answer (score 0):

Find myself

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_file_link(&$variables) {

    $file = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('some_url');
    $variables['link']['#url'] = $file;


}
```